# YouTube Oauth2 token problems

Tags: php, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I am wanting to get the current logged in YouTube users details for my site.
After some playing around, I found a way.
The problem is, depending on my "scope" parameter, I do not get all what I should be getting.

So here is an echo of some info I am looking at.

```
Author code:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   
RESULT code:
"{ "access_token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3599 }" 

channelId: xxxxxxxxxxxxx 
userId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
username: xxxxxxxxx
displayname: XxxxxxxXxxxx
```

So all looks good??? Well no.
For my immediate needs it will do, but not for long term.

The issue is as mentioned, the "scope" parameter.
If I set it to

> scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube

I can access the info, but it does not log it in the "Authorised Access" list in my Google account.
(so user is not authorised)
But if I set the scope to

> scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

it will log the access, but then I cant get the user info.
And this is the echo:

> .....failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Token invalid

I will be needing to have it log the user as authorised as well as get their channel info so that I can get my refresh token for later developments.

---

So is no one going to help with this issue?!?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try  scope=http://gdata.youtube.com.